# Why is this symbolic derivative zero?

Tags: derivatives, matlab, symbolic-computation

I'm trying to compute the derivative of this function with respect to $\theta$ (i.e., $\frac{dv}{d\theta}$):

$$
v(t) = m_2 a_1 a_2 \dot{\phi}(t)\dot{\theta}(t) \cos(\theta(t)-\phi(t))
$$

I thought the answer was:

$$
\frac{dv}{d\theta} = -m_2 a_1 a_2 \dot{\phi}(t)\dot{\theta}(t) \sin(\theta(t)-\phi(t))
$$

But Matlab yields zero using this script:

```
clear variables
clc
syms t a1 a2 m2 th(t) p(t) 
f = m2*a1*a2*diff(p,t)*diff(th,t)*cos(th-p);
v = sym('th');
dvdth = subs(diff(subs(f,th,v),v),v,th)
```

Is there any problem with the preceding script?

Comment: The part which is diff(th,t) in the script depends on $\theta$ (At least Matlab will interprete it this way). Also please explain the nested subst-command in the last line of the script.

Comment: @Peter, I've modified the script provided in here [How to implement a derivative of a symbolic function by a 'symfun' in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085362/how-to-implement-a-derivative-of-a-symbolic-function-by-a-symfun-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [example approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085362/how-to-implement-a-derivative-of-a-symbolic-function-by-a-symfun-in-matlab) that you cite is for a simpler situation. Your function `f` depends on not just abstract symbolic functions, but also their derivatives. The problem is that `subs(f,th,v)` by itself returns zero. This is because the substitution also replaces the `th(t)` inside `diff(th(t),t)` with a constant symbolic variable that is not a function of time. The derivative of a constant is zero so your entire function simplifies to zero.

To work with an equation like this you need to replace `diff(th(t),t)` with something else so that it is not impacted by the substitution. This can be done fairly painlessly by using the [multiple substitution](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#btqh71e-1) capabilities of [`sym/subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html):

```
syms t a1 a2 m2 th(t) p(t) 
v = m2*a1*a2*diff(p,t)*diff(th,t)*cos(th-p);
syms x dx
v2 = subs(v,{th,diff(th,t)},{x,dx}); % Order does not matter if done at same time
v3 = diff(v2,x);
dvdth = subs(v3,{x,dx},{th,diff(th,t)})
```

Or more compactly (but very hard to read):

```
syms t a1 a2 m2 th(t) p(t) x dx
v = m2*a1*a2*diff(p,t)*diff(th,t)*cos(th-p);
dvdth = subs(diff(subs(v,{th,diff(th,t)},{x,dx}),x),{x,dx},{th,diff(th,t)})
```

These returns `a1*a2*m2*sin(p(t) - th(t))*diff(p(t), t)*diff(th(t), t)`, which is equivalent to your expected result.

As I noted in my StackOverflow answer, this is, in my opinion, an ugly hack. One might be able turn this approach into a general function with a bit of work, but it might be quite challenging to handle every possible case.

Comment: Thank you @horchler for being informative and helpful. Running your script yields `a1*a2*m2*sin(p(t) - th(t))*diff(p(t), t)*diff(th(t), t)` but I don't understand why Matlab switches angles inside `sin`. Shouldn't be `sin(th(t) - p(t))`?

Comment: @CroCo: That's just how symbolic math works. There are lots of free choices and equivalent expressions when solving something symbolically. The same would be true for humans solving systems like this. Matlab tends to order variables alphabetically (try taking the derivative of `v` with respect to `p`).